# ArcGIS10.2 Field calculator problem with strings

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser, string

I am trying to do a simple concatenation using the ArcGIS 10.2 field calculator with Python code. I have a field of census tracts numbers (tract). I want to concatenate this with the numeric codes for the state and county so that I can join this table to the spatial geometry. The new field is defined as 'text'.

My code is "06085" + "!tract!" This yields the correct concatenation PLUS .0 on each record. So 0608512345.0

I have also tried str(06085)+str(!tract!) which yields the same results. What am I missing?

Comment: + str(int(!tract!))

Comment: @FelixIP, she would lose the leading zeros....I think there can be leading zeros on the tract number itself.

Comment: @Tom I see no mentioning of leading zeros, and if there are leading zeros on a tract, it makes it either non-numeric or decimal <1

Comment: @FelixIP, she didn't explicitly mention it, but the state FIPS code in her example has it, which suggests that the tract numbers might as well--and the fact that she says it's for census tracts, which can have leading zeros: https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/gtc/gtc_ct.html. However, you're right, that her field type must already be numeric...which could point to a other problems.

Answer (score 3):

So, you don't want the .0?

Then, you should use:

```
"06085{}".format( !Tract! ).split('.')[0]
```

Comment: Brilliant! This worked :-) Thank you! The US Census state FIPS codes do indeed have a leading zero which makes it much more difficult.

Comment: Can you help me understand the Python: why do the string commands format() or str() add a .0 on the end of numeric text? Is there a way to avoid this so I don't have to use the .split() ?

Comment: @AllisonMeezan, it must be that the "Tract" field is set to store floats or doubles. Because of that, Python is reading them with a decimal. But this also means that a simpler version should work: '06085{}'.format(str(!Tract!))

Answer (score 2):

Try `"06085{}.0".format( !Tract! )`

[image]

This yields the desired text output:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that yields the desired output. As far as I can tell, the whole point of the question was to get rid of the decimal--not to explicitly add it. Though the original question wasn't totally clear.

Comment: Yes, I realised that might be the case after I read your answer.  But I agree the question isn't clear